# What is the rod attached to the top of the Bell UH-1N's rotors?

Tags: helicopter

So, I was looking at an image of a Bell UH-1N, and noticed that the top if the rotor has a little stick or rod[image: this image]

What is this rod for? I also see this rod on a RC helicopter.

Answer (score 3):

It is a stabilizer bar used on some two blade helicopters. The spinning weights want to [stay in one plane](https://youtu.be/14vImhyar_Y?t=77) and are used in conjunction with the cyclic to control changes in pitch and roll. Depending on how it is designed, it counters these changes making the helicopter more stable (less maneuverable).

[image]

Comment: Means its less input needed on the pilots side?

Comment: @lpydawa Means slower response, so less twitchy.

Comment: is it to reduce the chance of pilot induced oscillation?

Comment: @lpydawa PIO results from overcontrolling, so a slower response from the aircraft probably makes PIO worse.

Comment: why would they want a slower response then?

Comment: The bar is a gyro which wants to remain level.  Its action on the rotor blade pitch angle mechanism causes the rotor itself to tend to seek a level plane of rotation, absent any input from the pilot's linkage, giving the helicopter's rotor a bit of stability it wouldn't normally have.  You could call it a "self-leveling servo" device.  So as Pilothead says, less twitchy, and a bit less tendency to wander off in any direction at any time.  In the Huey Cobra, which is based on the same machine, the bar was done away with because responsiveness was a priority.

Comment: @lpydawa What John said. It is a design choice, like how trucks handle differently than race cars. If you let go of the steering wheel of a truck it will go straight until it runs out of gas. If you let go of a formula1 wheel, the first crack in the pavement will send it into the weeds.

Comment: @lpydawa To avoid over-controlling the helicopter.  To provide more generic in flight stability.  See this answer about [stability versus maneuverability](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/12509/17262).

Comment: @JohnK that looks like a separate answer